# docker: Error Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable. IN DOCKER , WSL2

Tags: docker

I keep getting this error on my bash terminal using WSL2

```
C:\windows\system32>docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Service Unavailable.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to task manager, and End all Docker desktop Processes running.

then

```
docker logout
docker login
```

this worked for me